# Hard drive freezes all applications that access it

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ntfs, freeze, testdisk

I have a 2 month old WD Passport 4TB. On it is a NTFS partition or at least was. Since yesterday I’m unable to do anything with the hard drive. I was copying many files via rsync on it and suddenly it stopped. I tried to umount but it just freezes the terminal. Even the auto completion of the terminal froze when I tried to auto complete the mountpoint. So I had to pull the plug eventually.

If I try to access the hard drive now the file manager just freezes. But the hard drive is still visible via lsblk.

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0  3,7T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0  3,7T  0 part
```

I'm running `testdisk` now but the quick search is awfully slow. After 3 hours it looks like this.

```
Disk /dev/sdb1 - 4000 GB / 3725 GiB - CHS 486396 255 63
Analyse cylinder   110/486395: 00%
```

Is that hard drive completely dead now? Is there a way to restore the data on it?

Comment: Tried to read the S.M.A.R.T. data with `smartmontools`? Anything in the logs? Since it's a USB drive, what happens if you unplug-replug it?

Comment: Run `chkdsk <drive:> /x /r` from Windows _(Linux version for NTFS is subpar)_.  Once done, and to build on @xenoid's comment, run a short S.M.A.R.T test and view S.M.A.R.T data once test completes in 60s _(`smartctl -t short /dev/sdb; sleep 65; smartctl -a /dev/sdb`)_, then finally run a long S.M.A.R.T test, which takes several hours _(`smartctl -t long /dev/sdb` - to periodically check progress: `smartctl -a /dev/sdb | grep progress`)_.  Once the long test completes, re-review S.M.A.R.T data _(`smartctl -a /dev/sdb`)_. Provided there's not a hardware fault, `chkdsk` will correct the issue

Comment: Weird I just ran a the short scan with `smartctl` and now I can see it under `Removable devices` again. The applications also don't freeze anymore. Dolphin now throws the error `An error occurred while accessing 'Home', the system responded: An unspecified error has occurred: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired...`

I've tried ntfs-fix and it tells me to run `chkdsk`. When I'm home I'm going to plug it into my Windows computer and run `chkdsk`.

Comment: `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!` It's dead :(

Answer (score 0):

Your hard drive might be dead. I know it because I had an old external hard drive that was doing the same thing. It started off making some strange noises then it became very slow and then finally it stopped working.

Also, try and check your USB ports.

Do you have important files that you have backed-up elsewhere besides that WD Passport? Does it make any strange noises?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the USB ports. I've checked it on two different computers and systems. It also makes no noise, so I guess (and hope) it's not a hardware issue.